# In React Native is it possible to reload into the same screen I am working in?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have an app that I am developing in React Native, using Expo. When I make a change to a deeply nested screen, I have to navigate back to that screen to check my changes.

Is it possible to configure React Native or Expo to go back to that screen after a reload?

I'm not sure if it matter, but I'm also using React-Navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Running the app on a live device , Changes will be reflected directly on screen rather than going to root

Comment: This is new since my question was posted. It does work that way now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is just switch the routes in the navigator config so that deeply nested screen is the first route... then you can work on it and make changes, and when you’re done just reset the routes to what they’re supposed to be. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. That will work to and if there isn't a way to automate this then I will go with that